# Why is 'pip install json' showing version error

Tags: python, json

While I wrote 'pip install json' on my command prompt, it is giving an error - ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement json (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for json
What should I do

Comment: `json` is a stdlib module - you're not supposed to install it separately.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Json is a standard library in python there's no need to install it.

Just include it in your python script as the following

```
import json
```